# get array of array values from multidimensional array on PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops

#### What i get.

This is the array which i get in my form post form multiple check boxes.

```
$test1 = array(
    '0' => 'test1',
    '1' => 'test2',
    '2' => 'test3'  
);


$test2 = array(
    '0' => 'test21',
    '1' => 'test22',
    '2' => 'test23' 
);


$test3 = array(
    '0' => 'test31',
    '1' => 'test32',
    '2' => 'test33' 
);


$test4 = array(
    '0' => 'test41',
    '1' => 'test42',
    '2' => 'test43' 
);
```

I need to convert this array in to something like this:

#### Result needed.

```
$result_needed = [ 
    
    '0' => ['0' => 'test1', '1' => 'test21', '2' => 'test31', '3' => 'test41'],
    '1' => ['0' => 'test2', '1' => 'test22', '2' => 'test32', '3' => 'test42'],
AND SO ON....
];
```

#### What i have tried so far?

I have tried to add this each array in to final array and then used foreach loop on it it get the result but it didn't help. Here is what i tried.

```
$final = ['test1' => $test1, 'test2' => $test2, 'test3' => $test3, 'test4' => $test4];


echo "<pre>";

$step1 = array();

foreach($final as $key => $val){
    
    $step1[$key] = $val;    
    
}

print_r($step1);
```

Comment: In your loop write `$step1[] = $val;` instead of `$step1[$key] = $val;`

Comment: you need to use array_push()

Comment: Let me know that all four input array will be always same length or can be changed?

Comment: All the array has same element everytime or each has different?

Comment: Array push is not helping me to get the desired result sir @BarclickFloresVelasquez

Comment: 4 array is final but array value must and count of each is not defined is it correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with loops and pushing to result array

```
$final = ['test1' => $test1, 'test2' => $test2, 'test3' => $test3, 'test4' => $test4];

$step1 = [];
foreach ($final as $tests) {
    foreach ($tests as $key => $value) {
        if (!array_key_exists($key, $step1)) {
            $step1[$key] = [];
        }

        $step1[$key][] = $value;
    }
}

print_r($step1);
```

Answer (score 1):

If all the array has same length and all are index array.

```
$result = array();

foreach($test1 as $key=> $test){
    $result[] = [$test1[$key],$test2[$key],$test3[$key],$test4[$key]];
}

print_r($result);
```